# Multiple JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, join

Im trying to retrieve stage, batch, tasks and employees assigned to the task for a project and I'm almost done but I just can't quite understand why the result become empty whenever I try to include the `employee` table.
This is my original statement :

```
SELECT project.JONumber, stage.StageName, batch.BatchName, tasks.task_name, tasks_assignment.employee_number
    FROM project 
    JOIN stage ON project.id = stage.project_id 
    JOIN batch ON stage.ID = batch.stage_id
    JOIN tasks ON batch.id = tasks.batch_id
    JOIN tasks_assignment ON tasks.id = tasks_assignment.task_id
    WHERE project.id = 23441;
```

But when I try to add another `JOIN` statement, the result returns empty, 
Here is the updated statement :

```
SELECT project.JONumber, stage.StageName, batch.BatchName, tasks.task_name, tasks_assignment.employee_number, employee.FirstName
FROM project 
JOIN stage ON project.id = stage.project_id 
JOIN batch ON stage.ID = batch.stage_id
JOIN tasks ON batch.id = tasks.batch_id
JOIN tasks_assignment ON tasks.id = tasks_assignment.task_id
JOIN employee ON employee.ID=tasks_assignment.employee_number
WHERE project.id = 23441;
```

I'm thinking that maybe I messed up the last JOIN statement but isn't it that JOIN should be like `JOIN table2 ON table1.Primarykey=table2.foreignkey`. But maybe I'm wrong, could anyone point out my mistake please? I'm just really confused

Comment: Your sql seems fine to me. I'd look up the concerning entries of the `employee` table manually, to see wether they exist, have the correct format etc.. If that doesn't find the error, edit the question with some examples of your database.

Comment: @TheHowlingHoaschd yep I checked it manually and it seems that the one who made the table put 2 ID's for the employee table, one being the index and another one for the actual employee ID.

Answer (score 0):

try like this once

```
SELECT project.JONumber, stage.StageName, batch.BatchName, tasks.task_name, tasks_assignment.employee_number, employee.FirstName
FROM project 
JOIN stage ON project.id = stage.project_id 
JOIN batch ON stage.ID = batch.stage_id
JOIN tasks ON batch.id = tasks.batch_id
JOIN tasks_assignment ON tasks.id = tasks_assignment.task_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN employee ON employee.ID=tasks_assignment.employee_number
WHERE project.id = 23441;
```